# How to make the ball bounce from top to bottom?

Tags: python, pygame

I'm making a simple pong game, and I want the ball to bounce back and forth from top to bottom. I know I have to modify "test_collide_top_ball and test_collide_bottom_ball" in my code to do this (found in the second block of code below), but I'm a bit unsure if my logic/solution is correct.

So, if I want the ball to bounce in the other direction when it hits the top height, is it reasonable to say something like: "self.y = self.y - dy"? And same for when the ball hits the bottom height, except instead of subtracting you add?

And I'm a bit confused as to how to make the ball move in the base code. Thanks in advance!

Here's my base code:

```
import math
import random
import sys, pygame
from pygame.locals import *

import ball
import colors
import paddle

# draw the scene
def draw(screen, ball1, paddle1) :
   screen.fill((128, 128, 128))
   ball1.draw_ball(screen)
   paddle1.draw_paddle(screen)

#function to start up the main drawing
def main():

   pygame.init()
   width = 600
   height = 600
   screen = pygame.display.set_mode((width, height))

   ball1 = ball.Ball(300, 1, 40, colors.RED)
   paddle1 = paddle.Paddle(100, 575, colors.BLUE, 100, 20)

   while 1:
      for event in pygame.event.get():
         if event.type == QUIT: sys.exit()
         elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
               paddle1.update_paddle('right', 15)
            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
               paddle1.update_paddle('left', 15)

      draw(screen, ball1, paddle1)
      pygame.display.flip()

if __name__ == '__main__':
   main()
```

And here's my class/methods for the ball:

```
import pygame

class Ball:
   def __init__(self, x, y, radius, color):
      self.x = x
      self.y = y
      self.radius = radius
      self.color = color

   def draw_ball(self, screen):
      pygame.draw.ellipse(screen, self.color,
         pygame.Rect(self.x, self.y, self.radius, self.radius))

   def update_ball(self, dx, dy):
      self.x += dx
      self.y += dy

   def test_collide_top_ball(self, top_height):
      if (self.y == top_height):
         return True
      else:
         return False

   def test_collide_bottom_ball(self, coll_height):
      if (self.y == coll_height):
         return True
      else:
         return False
```

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the `self.y` of the ball and the width are rarely ever "equal". Therefore, you should check whether the ball is beyond the bounds of the screen. You should have your update method as:

[NOTE] The `dx` and `dy` variables should be variables of the class and **NOT** passed in from outside

```
def update_ball(self, dx, dy, screen_w, screen_h):  #added screen width and height parameters
    self.x += self.dx
    self.y += self.dy
    if self.y > screen_h:
        self.y -= 5
        self.dy *= -1
    elif self.y < 0:
        self.y += 5
        self.dy *= -1
    if self.x > screen_w:
        self.x -= 5
        self.dx *= -1
    elif self.x < 0:
        self.x += 5
        self.dx *= -1
```

Comment: So if I had to use the methods I've written to test_collide_top_ball and bottom ball, what does that mean? Would I have to use those in if statements in the base code to determine whether or not self.y is equal to the top or bottom height? And then use update_ball within those if statements to actually move the ball? Thanks!

Comment: @Karen, Actually this method is enough by itself. You just call it once in your main `while` loop and it will take care of __all__ collision cases.